# Is it Possible to perform input field clearing with an Angular directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want a form to toggle the visibility of an input field based on selecting a checkbox. This is easily achieved using the ng-show directive. However if the user un-checks the checkbox i would like the input field to hide and have its value(s) cleared. I want to do this without resorting to creating a controller for this.
Can i do this with a directive?

Comment: Can you show that part of your template? Sometimes you can do tricks with `ng-if` in combination with `ng-init` albeit that becomes a bit hacky.

Comment: What's wrong with using a controller for this?

Comment: This functionality is being used across the application on many different forms. I wanted to perhaps use a directive instead of repeating the code on every other form controller.